# Proper definition of well-founded induction on a class

Tags: logic, induction, set-theory, transfinite-induction

On Wikipedia it says that a binary relation $R$ on a class $X$ is well-founded if every non-empty subset $S \subseteq X$ contains a minimal element, i.e. there is some $x \in S$ such that $(y,x) \notin R$ for all $y \in S$. Then if we have a set-like (for every $x \in X$ the subclass $\{ y \colon (y,x) \in R \}$ is a set), well-founded relation $R$ on a class $X$, then we can perform induction on $R$.

I'm wondering if the above definition of well-founded relation is really sufficient for induction on a class. Is it not actually necessary for every **subclass** of $X$ to have a minimal element?

I understand that the sketch of the proof that the induction works goes as follows. Suppose that for some proposition we have proven that for any $x \in X$ if this proposition is true for all $y \in X$ such that $(y,x) \in R$, then it is also true for $x$. Now we can prove by contradiction that the proposition is therefore true for all $x \in X$. Assume that there exists some $x \in X$ for which the proposition fails. Let $C \subseteq X$ be the non-empty **subclass** of $X$ consisting of all counterexamples. There is a minimal element $x \in C$ and so the proposition is true for all $(y,x) \in R$. But by our assumption if the proposotion is true for all $(y,x) \in R$, then it is also true for $x$, which contradicts that $x$ is a counterexample.

In this proof I used the stronger version of well-foundedness that says all subclasses have minimal elements. My question is if there is an alternative proof that does not need this stronger version of well-foundedness, or if the proper definition of well-founded induction on a class actually needs this stronger version.

If it is the latter then is there a name for such a relation, e.g. a *strongly* well-founded relation?

EDIT:
I'm asking if well-foundedness in the weaker sense + set-likeness is sufficient for induction on a class, or if one needs well-foundedness in the stronger sense + set-likeness.

Comment: Are you asking if well-foundedness (in the weaker sense) is sufficient, or if well-foundedness + set-like-ness is sufficient? The answers are "no" and "yes".

Comment: I'm asking if well-foundedness in the weaker sense + set-likeness is sufficient.

Comment: Oh, I wrote my answer asssuming you meant the other question (whether set-like-ness can be dropped).  The answer is actually still yes, assuming the axiom of regularity.

Comment: @EricWofsey Oh, yes, that's right. *recursion* (not induction) is what breaks when we drop set-like-ness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the stronger version of well-foundedness.  The idea is that any failure of well-foundedness is in some sense "local" and can be witnessed on just a set.

Let me first sketch the argument intuitively.  Suppose there is a nonempty subclass $C\subseteq X$ with no minimal element.  Pick an element $c_0\in C$.  Since $c_0$ is not minimal, you can pick $c_1\in C$ such that $c_1Rc_0$.  Since $c_1$ is not minimal, you can pick $c_2\in C$ such that $c_2Rc_1$.  Continuing recursively, you can pick a sequence $(c_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of elements of $C$ such that $c_{n+1}Rc_n$ for each $n$.  But now consider $\{c_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$.  This is a *set* by Replacement since $\mathbb{N}$ is a set, and has no minimal element, which is a contradiction.

Now, there are some technical issues with this argument as stated.  To actually carry out this recursion, we need to use the axiom of choice to choose our infinitely many $c_n$'s.  Moreover, doing so requires us to fix a choice function ahead of time, which must be defined on a *set* (the axiom of choice only applies to sets, not classes), so we need to know ahead of time there is a set from which we will be making all our choices.  The trick now is that we can use the set-like condition on $R$ to find such a set.  And in fact, once we've found such a set, we can formulate the argument to avoid using the axiom of choice.

Here's how it works.  After picking $c_0$, instead of picking a single $c_1\in C$ such that $c_1Rc_0$, we take the set $C_1$ of *all* such elements $c_1$, which is a set since $R$ is set-like.  For convenience, let me give a name to the operation we just did: if $c\in C$, let $F(c)$ be the set of all $d\in C$ such that $dRc$.  So we've defined $C_1=F(c_0)$

Now for the next step, we'd like to do the same thing and define $C_2=F(c_1)$, except that we don't have a single element $c_1$ but instead an entire set $C_1$ of "candidate" values for $c_1$.  That's no problem; we just do it for all our candidates.  That is, we define $C_2=\bigcup_{c\in C_1}F(c)$.  We can continue this recursively to define a sequence $(C_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of sets such that $C_0=\{c_0\}$ and $C_{n+1}=\bigcup_{c\in C_n}F(c)$ for each $n$.

Now if we take $S=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} C_n$, this $S$ is a *set* and we can carry out our original intuitive argument by fixing a choice function on its nonempty sets ahead of time.  Actually, though, we don't even need to make that argument.  We can just directly observe that $S$ has no minimal element: any $c\in S$ is in some $C_n$, and then $F(c)\subseteq C_{n+1}\subseteq S$.  Since $c$ is not minimal in $C$, $F(c)$ is nonempty, and any element of it witnesses that $c$ is not minimal in $S$.

Finally, let me remark that assuming the axiom of regularity, you don't even need to assume that $R$ is set-like, since you can use [Scott's trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott%27s_trick).  Namely, in the argument above, instead of letting $F(c)$ be the set of all $d\in C$ such that $dRc$ (which may not be a set if $R$ is not set-like), you can let $F(c)$ be the set of all such $d$ of *minimal rank*.  That is, let $\alpha$ be the least ordinal such that there exists $d\in C\cap V_\alpha$ such that $dRc$, and then let $F(c)$ be the set of all such $d\in C\cap V_\alpha$ (which is a set since $V_\alpha$ is a set).  With this modified definition of $F$, the rest of the argument still works just as before.

Comment: Thank you, that's a very clear and enlightening answer. I find it very elegant that well-foundedness by itself is sufficient for induction. Although spaceisdarkgreen's comment suggests that set-like-ness is necessary for recursion.

Comment: The problem with recursion is that you can't even *state* what recursion means without set-like-ness.  You want to say that the value of your recursively defined function $f$ on an element $x\in C$ is determined by some operation applied to the restriction of $f$ to $\{y\in C:yRx\}$, but if that's not a set you can't even formulate applying an "operation" to it in the language of set theory.

Comment: And even in special cases where you could formulate it, *proving* recursion involves quantification over these restrictions of $f$, which you can't do if they are proper classes.